# Magento 2 : Overriding CatalogWidget's ProductsList block

Tags: product, magento-2.1, overrides, widget

I'm trying to override Magento_CatalogWidget's ProductsList block the following way, but unsuccessfully.

I have created a new module (app/code/MY_NAMESPACE/CatalogWidget), its tree structure is:

```
├── Block
│   └── Product
│       └── ProductsList.php
├── etc
│   ├── di.xml
│   └── module.xml
└── registration.php
```

The content of di.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" type="MY_NAMESPACE\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" />
</config>
```

The content of ProductsList.php is:

```
<?php

namespace MY_NAMESPACE\CatalogWidget\Block\Product;

class ProductsList extends \Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList
{
    public function myTest()
    {
        die('Hello World !');
    }
}

?>
```

To test it, I have also overridden (in a custom theme) the file grid.phtml from Magento_CatalogWidget module:

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog-widget/view/frontend/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml
```

The line below has been add to this grid.phtml in order to list the methods of the block:

```
print_r(get_class_methods($block));
```

But I can't see the method myTest() in the list, why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed this problem by adding the file grid.phtml directly to my module, instead of the custom theme. The tree structure of my module is now as follow:

```
├── Block
│   └── Product
│       └── ProductsList.php
├── etc
│   ├── di.xml
│   └── module.xml
├── registration.php
└── view
    └── frontend
        └── templates
            └── product
                └── widget
                    └── content
                        └── grid.phtml
```

But I still don't understand why I had to add this file here and why it doesn't work without it.